# DataVisualization Tooltip behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, tooltip

I've successfully setup my XAML to retrieve a custom tooltip generated in my viewmodel; however, when I run in debug mode and place a break at the "getter", I see that while building my chart, it is hitting the "getter" numerous times.  What I don't understand is why is it hitting the "getter" while building the chart?  Are tooltips built when the chart is built, making them somewhat static in nature.

If that's the case, my guess is it's building the tooltip for each datapoint; then how would I get access to the current datapoint in my tooltip "getter".

Comment: Code would help. And a stack trace at the break point.

Comment: Thanks for the interest.  However, after much experimenting, I decided to just put a value converter on each of the series' independent/dependent values and inside the converter format what I wanted in the tooltip.  I was originally trying to use someone elses code that I found on the internet and that often proves troublesome.  The approach the other individual used is to bind a property to the tooltip, with the property being an object containing a textbox and some values.  While it obviously worked for him, it didn't for me probably because he didn't post the entire source, just snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for my cynical response, but having let it sit for quite a few days, I was getting frustrated.  In the end I chose a different approach.  But I did not find an answer to my questions in the original approach.  I settled on using a value converter rather than bind the tooltip to an object containing a textbox.  Originally, I was trying to set the textbox up so that it displayed values from all 3 series in my graph, but couldn't figure out how to do that.  Gert Arnold suggested I post code and a stacktrace, but there's a lot of code and I didn't know how to get at the stacktrace during a breakpoint.